# Raphael dot chart gives javascript error

Tags: raphael

I implemented the following:

```
<div id="b1xy" class="dot-graph"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var r = Raphael("b1xy","100%","100%");
r.dotchart(10, 0, 400,200, [76, 70, 67, 71, 69], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [100, 120, 140, 160, 500], {max: 10, axisylabels: ['Mexico', 'Argentina', 'Cuba', 'Canada', 'United States of America'], heat: true, axis: '0 0 1 1'});
</script>
```

But this gave the javascript error `Error: Problem parsing d="M,0,0"`.  Does anyone know what's wrong? How do I print a dot chart?

I've included the jquery library, raphael.js, g.raphael.js and g.dot.js, so i know I have all the tools necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  My jQuery was version 1.4 and was too old, so raphael couldn't work with it.  I upgraded my jQuery to 1.8 and everything was fine.

Comment: Raphael is jQuery independent, and I see no jquery code in your question. Is it that your problem was in the part of the code you did not show?